# Text field passed to MySQL StoredProcedure from PDO saves '0' instead of passed string

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, stored-procedures, pdo

I am using a MySQL stored procedure to insert into/update a table that includes a field of type TEXT, calling the stored procedure using PDO.  When I execute the stored procedure from PHPMyAdmin it works perfectly, but when I call it in code using PDO, a "0" is saved in the TEXT field rather than the string that was passed.

There is another string field of type Varchar(200) which works fine.

AJAX passes the variables to the PHP script using the POST method.  I am sure that the AJAX call completes this successfully as the PHP script can echo the string passed.

STORED PROCEDURE LISTING:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SaveProjectHeader`(IN `iProjectId` INT, IN `sProjectName` VARCHAR(200) CHARSET utf8, IN `iProjectOwnerId` INT, IN `sProjectDescription` TEXT CHARSET utf8, IN `iSubProjectOfId` INT, IN `dTargetEndDate` DATE, IN `iTargetBudget` INT, OUT `sSPResult` VARCHAR(20) CHARSET utf8)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    COMMENT 'Basic save routine for ProjectHeaders'
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET sSPResult = 'FAIL';
  SET sSPResult = 'DONE';
  IF iProjectId = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO Projects (ProjectName, ProjectOwnerId, SubProjectOfId, ProjectDescription, TargetEndDate, TargetBudget) VALUES (sProjectName, iProjectOwnerId, iSubProjectOfId, sProjectDescription, dTargetEndDate, iTargetBudget);
        SET iProjectId=last_insert_id();
    ELSE
        UPDATE Projects SET ProjectName=sProjectName, ProjectOwnerId=iProjectOwnerId, ProjectDescription=sProjectDescription, SubProjectOfId=iSubProjectOfId, TargetEndDate=dTargetEndDate, TargetBudget=iTargetBudget WHERE ProjectId=iProjectId;
    END IF;
END
```

TABLE STRUCTURE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `projectid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `projectname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `projectownerid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subprojectofid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `projectdescription` text,
  `targetenddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `targetbudget` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`projectid`),
  KEY `projectowner` (`projectownerid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=40 ;
```

PHP SCRIPT LISTING:

```
<?php
header("Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
session_start();

//Create string for debugging purposes; start with input params
$s="";
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){$s.= $key."=".$value."<BR/>";}


 // Use Namespaces with alias
use gis\general as gisgen;
use gis\projectmgr as gispm;

// Commence output buffering
ob_start();

//Connect to database
require_once("LocalizationHelper.php"); 
require_once("/home/".$DBIDPath."/MySQLConns/".$DBIDPath.".php"); 

// CLASS LIBRARIES
require_once("class_lib.php");
require_once("class_lib_projectmgr.php");

// PHP FUNCTION LIBRARIES
//
//  Miscellaneous standard functions
require_once("s_MiscFuncsPHPv3.inc");
require_once("s_DateFuncsPHPv1.inc");

$SAVECOMMAND=         $_POST["SAVECOMMAND"];
$COMMAND=             $_POST["COMMAND"];  
$ProjectId=           $_POST["ProjectId"];
$ProjectName=         $_POST["ProjectName"];
$ProjectOwnerId=      $_POST["ProjectOwnerId"];
$SubProjectOfId=      $_POST["SubProjectOfId"];
$ProjectDescription=  $_POST["ProjectDescription"];
$TargetEndDate=       EnglishToDBDate($_POST["TargetEndDate"]); // to yyyy-mm-dd format
$TargetBudget=        str_replace(",","",$_POST["TargetBudget"]);//remove commas from number string

//Append modified input parameters to debugging string
$s.="TargetEndDate=".$TargetEndDate."<br />";
$s.="TargetBudget=".$TargetBudget."<br />";


$oUser = new gisgen\LoggedInUser($DBH, $_SESSION["UserID"]);

try{
  //Form callto SP to save ProjectHeader
  $SQL = 'CALL SaveProjectHeader(:ProjectId,:ProjectName,:ProjectOwnerId,:SubProjectOfId,:ProjectDescription,:TargetEndDate,:TargetBudget,@SPResult)';

  //Prepare SQL command
  $STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);

  //Bind parameters to command
  $STH->bindParam(':ProjectId',$ProjectId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $STH->bindParam(':ProjectName',$ProjectName,PDO::PARAM_STR,200);
  $STH->bindParam(':ProjectOwnerId',$ProjectOwnerId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $STH->bindParam(':SubProjectOfId',$SubProjectOfId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $STH->bindParam(':ProjectDescription',$ProjectDescription,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $STH->bindParam(':TargetEndDate',$TargetEndDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $STH->bindParam(':TargetBudget',$TargetBudget,PDO::PARAM_INT);

  //Execute
  $STH->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error occurred :" . $e->getMessage()."<hr />".$s);
}

//Assemble new HTML summary for display in DIV ProjectHeader
$oProject = new gispm\Project($DBH, $ProjectId, $_SESSION["UserID"]);
include 'ProjectHeaderPaint.php';
echo "<hr />".$s;

//Finished with DB handle
$DBH=null;
?>
```

The PHP script listed above is called by AJAX, and serves two purposes;

1. To call the SP to save the data supplied by a  within a given , and
2. To return a neatly formatted piece of HTML showing the data saved which replaces the  in the .

My thanks in advance to anyone who can help with this problem.

Comment: Never in my life I'll understand why use a procedure for simple insert

Comment: @YourCommonSense it would be boring otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I want to use a stored procedure as in the final version it will simplify our security access (user control will be down to field level) and guard against SQL injection. The finished version will do a lot more than a single INSERT/UPDATE operation, and also I want to find out how to make this work (or why it won't.)